# How to set a project as startup project in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have two projects in `PyCharm`, which are called `A` and `B`...

Each one has several files in addition to a `main` file, i.e. `a_main.py` and `b_main.py`

How can I switch between two projects for choosing one to be run? In other words, how could it be possible to select the start up project?

Comment: What do you mean *"start up project"*? Do you mean the one that appears when you start PyCharm? Or something else (if so, what)?

Comment: ''The start up project" is the one that when I press `Ctrl+F5`, its `main` file will be executed...

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration.html?

Comment: I've glanced at it... But I found nothing to address my issue...

Comment: Well there's lots of material linked from it, so you should probably do more than glancing. We aren't here to read the manual for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you work with Visual Studio for some time? the concept of start up project does not exist in pycharm.

When you open a project, you can add more projects on the same window, and you can run each .py file whenever you like.

Use `alt+shift+f10` to choose the file you want to run, or `shift+f10` to rerun the latest file you ran.

for more information check [this out](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configurations.html).

Comment: I need to declare my deep gratitude for your contribution, which deservedly hit the mark!... Thank you...

Comment: @Ordenador that page in this answer is the first link from the page I sent you. Please make more of an effort to read the documentation in the future; PyCharm's docs are pretty good.